# Pikaday - Multiple Inputs Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I have tried to attach pikaday to multiple elements.

It seems like this is possible with the JQuery plugin.

Does anyone know if it is possible with Vanilla JS?

Here is the code:

http://bit.ly/IFM3De

Note: Will add it to the question once I have more information

Pikaday Plugin - https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

Comment: Please include the code in your question. jsFiddles are a nice addition, but they are not sufficient. What if jsFiddle is not available one day? Also, don't use URL shortener, I'd argue that people are less likely to follow those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using brackets. You need to use square braces to get a property of an object.

```
var eleGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.date-picker');

for(x in eleGroup) {
    if(eleGroup.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        new Pikaday({ field: eleGroup[x] });
    }
}
```