# Can't use Pikaday on more than 1 element when targetting by class

Tags: jquery

I'm using Pikaday and trying to get it to work on 2 inputs, targeting by class.

My inputs look like this:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="start_date" value="">
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="end_date" value="">
```

I've read the documentation on attaching it to multiple inputs (https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/2) and adapted this to use my class name of `.datepicker` so my js looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').each(function() {
        $(this).data('pikaday', new Pikaday({ field: $(this) }));
    });
});
```

Every example on that link above does not work for me. Why is this?

Comment: Can you please provide a working example that states your problem?

Comment: This works in plain JavaScript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333104/pikaday-multiple-inputs-vanilla-javascript - but would prefer to know if it's possible in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making use of the *element* parameter of the *each()* method:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').each(function(index, element) {
    new Pikaday({
      field: element,
      position: 'bottom left',
      reposition: false
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://dbushell.com/Pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="start_date" value="">
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="end_date" value="">
```